# Production server not working: Ruby 2.3.0 on Rails 5.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am working through "The Essential Web Developer Course (Free)" at http://upskillcourses.com and have encountered a problem that I haven't been able to sort out.

My work to date can be found at this github.com link:

https://github.com/josua111/upskill_saas_tutorial

My problem:

Running the server in developer mode has been working, but when I sent it to heroku it would not work. I tried running it in production mode in cloud9 also using the following:

```
$ rails server -e production
```

It did not work and got the following feedback from the terminal:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': Invalid option key: raise_on_unfiltered_parameters= (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:54:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:263:in `<class:Base>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:117:in `exclusive'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:336:in `depend_on'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Heroku's  Application Logs show the following:

```
2017-09-14T20:07:32.907315+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
2017-09-14T20:07:32.907330+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2017-09-14T20:07:32.907331+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2017-09-14T20:07:32.907332+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2017-09-14T20:07:32.907333+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2017-09-14T20:07:32.907347+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-09-14T20:07:32.907347+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-09-14T20:07:33.082126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-14T20:07:33.067518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-09-14T20:08:49.126236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-atoll-96914.herokuapp.com request_id=4e1037eb-4003-4b6a-ad8b-77bca1690294 fwd="70.89.11.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-14T20:08:49.633665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-atoll-96914.herokuapp.com request_id=f3d2b017-0a7a-4248-8843-804eae6b4a83 fwd="70.89.11.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

No progress w/ google. I have a lot of learning to do. I'm not quite sure where to start with these logs.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you search for all occurrences of `raise_on_unfiltered_parameters`? This should be something like `config.action_controller.raise_on_unfiltered_parameters` and maybe you misstype it?

Comment: @NilColor Search came back with : /saasapp/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:
 7: Rails.application.config.action_controller.raise_on_unfiltered_parameters = true

Comment: Can you try to remove this line?

Comment: @NilColor I removed that line from `/saasapp/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb` and the server started up, but now I am getting a different error : Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`> and my browser reads this message : `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.`

Comment: you can generate new secret using `rails secret` command and paste it into secrets.yml file for production env. Check this sample https://github.com/heroku/ruby-rails-sample/blob/master/config/secrets.yml

Comment: @NilColor This worked, but not my application is not rendering properly: no css, and one of my three pages just gives an error.

Comment: in heroku deploy, do you see `assets:precompile` ? If you are expecting it to work locally in production mode, it won't work because assets compilation is a part of a production deploy process.

Comment: @josua111check this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5